# How to know the angle at which different images of a 3d object are being clicked?

Tags: image-processing, 3d

So , I want to create a 3d model from 2d images being clicked by my cell. I want to know the angle at which they are clicked as to sort and upload them on autocad recap ( I know we can upload as many images as we want ) but still need to reduce the number of images according to the angle at which they are being clicked.

Comment: I think this is too broad a question for SO. You need to highlight a specific question. It is advisable that you show your code, sample data and the expected results.

Comment: I am sorry but i have zero knowledge how to proceed on this .On a broader expect, what I need to do is that I have to sort images as per the angles at which they are clicked and taking the first image clicked as the reference image.
I am sorry but I have 0 idea how to make this work .